# How to put a view in exact column and row and make it fill that column GridLayout android

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, android-gridlayout

i am having some issues here regarding grid layout. 
Lets say that i have a grid layout that covers the whole screen and which has fixed row and column count (eg. 8/8). Now lets say that i want to insert 2 custom views that only match that column and row that they were inserted into.

image example:
[image]

i am sorry if the picture is bad :D Have in mind that column width and height is fixed to the device screen and the views should not spread it, instead they should fill that 1 column. I am sure that it is possible to achieve this but unfortunately i have not found a solution till now. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!!!!

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context="com.example.luka.gridlayouttest.FullscreenActivity"
    android:columnCount="12"
    android:rowCount="12"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="true"
    android:rowOrderPreserved="true">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="3"/>

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_row="4"
        android:layout_column="6" />
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: Made a grid layout that matches parent with a row and column count of 12 . Added a textView tried to move around it on the screen, played around with weight, span width and height. I can not get to move it from the top left corner even if the column and row changes except if i change weight or span then the text view just eats empty rows and columns... I bet that it is a stupid question but i really never had to use grid layout...

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried?

Comment: I've inserted the code into the original question, the point of this is to just put element in columns and rows of my choosing, simple as that...But yet so complicated hehehe :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it correctly.  You're just not complete.  The undefined views essentially have a zero size.  If you add something like

```
android:text="row0, col0"
android:layout_row="0"
android:layout_column="0"/>

android:text="row1, col1"
android:layout_row="1"
android:layout_column="1"/>
```

etc, you will see your `TextView`s going diagonally down to the right.  It seems you have to populate every view in the grid for it to give you the complete grid.  For each view, you either have to give it a fixed size (instead of `wrap_content`) or fill it with something (using `android:text="row0, col0"`).